# How to make this layout with Java swing?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I have the following layout:

[image]

The red, blue and green parts are JPanel. In the red part I have four JLabel. Now if I resize the JFrame, the title labels always stay in the center. But I would prefer if they are evenly distributed horizontaly in the red part. Which layout should I use for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a GridLayout(1, 0) for the top JPanel.  The two numbers means 1 row and variable number of columns. If you are using JLabels, this will be sufficient, especially if you set the JLabels alignment constant to SwingConstants.CENTER. If you are using components that fill the grid slots, such as JButtons, then you may need to use other variants of the GridLayout constructor, such as GridLayout(1, 0, ?, 0) Where the ? is a number that tells the GridLayout how much horizontal separation there should be between slots.

The overall GUI would use a BorderLayout of course.

For more and better information on this, please check out [Lesson: Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.*;

public class LayoutEg {

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      String[] labelStrings = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four"};
      JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
      for (String labelString : labelStrings) {
         // create labels and center the text
         topPanel.add(new JLabel(labelString, SwingConstants.CENTER)); 
      }
      topPanel.setBackground(Color.red);

      JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
      centerPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);

      // setting preferred size for demonstration purposes only
      centerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 400));

      JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
      bottomPanel.setBackground(Color.green);

      // main panel uses BorderLayout
      JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      mainPanel.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      mainPanel.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
      mainPanel.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);


      JFrame frame = new JFrame("LayoutEg");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a BorderLayout for the frame's content pane, and use a GridLayout with 1 row and four columns for the title panel.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html for tutorials.

If you don't want the same width assigned to each label, but in fact want the same space between every label, you may also use a BoxLayout, and add a glue between each label (and between the border of the panel and the label:

```
p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
p.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
p.add(new JLabel("Label"));
p.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
p.add(new JLabel("Long Label"));
p.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
p.add(new JLabel("Very long Label"));
p.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
p.add(new JLabel("Extremely long Label"));
p.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems no to be evenly distributed

Comment: safiest and in almost of cases accepting min & max & preferred size +1

Answer (score 3):

- Use a `BorderLayout` for the main frame and use the `NORTH`, `CENTER` and `SOUTH` places.
- To create empty space like in the bottom panel, use `Box.createVerticalStrut(size)`.
- Use `BoxLayout` to place the labels packed in a row.
- Finally use `GridBagLayout` to center a panel in another Panel.

Here is a short example:

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Prototype extends JFrame {

    public Prototype() {

        JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel();
        labelPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(labelPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        labelPanel.add(new JLabel("First"));
        labelPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
        labelPanel.add(new JLabel("Second"));
        labelPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
        labelPanel.setOpaque(false);

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(15));
        bottomPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(200, 300)));
        centerPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        JPanel northPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        northPanel.add(labelPanel);
        northPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        add(panel);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Prototype();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/).

No, seriously, I used to go crazy trying to get Java layouts working. Then I started maintaining some software that uses MigLayouts, and after a week or so I could do anything I wanted. There is an excellent [cheat sheet](http://migcalendar.com/miglayout/cheatsheet.html) that looks pretty intimidating, but it's incredibly helpful.

With a MigLayout, to have evenly spread labels in a JPanel you would:

```
// the "fillx" means that the layout will expand to take up all available horizontal space
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new Miglayout("fillx"));

// the "growx" means that the component will expand to take up all available horizontal space
add(new JLabel("Work items"), "growx");
add(new JLabel("Change set"), "growx");
add(new JLabel("Files"), "growx");
add(new JLabel("Source code"), "growx");
```

Comment: if it is possible achieve something using Swing Layout why use 3rd party layout? do u dare to fear the wraith of swing?

Comment: I'm betting that not only does he knows how to do this easily in Swing, but that he has also found a simpler more fool-proof way to do this and more importantly, *more complex layouts*, and does not fear to enhance Swing when and where necessary. 1+ vote.

Answer (score 1):

gridLayout, put the labels into the grid layout and set rows to 1 and columns to 4 (1 row for each Label)

http://www.javabeginner.com/java-swing/java-gridlayout-class-example

Answer (score 0):

[GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) is one approach. Set the weightx value to 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

For labels to be distributed evenly horizantally - in the red panel - use BoxLayout with X_AXIS direction and put 'glue' between each label - More here -

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html